# The error when start jekyll server

Tags: git, ubuntu, nginx, jekyll, cron

My Cloud Server is Ubuntu 14, after I install jekyll and start it like `sudo jekyll serve --port 80 --host 'my server ip address'`, it shows errors like below:

```
   Configuration file: /home/ubuntu/mydomain.com/_config.yml
   Deprecation: You appear to have pagination turned on, but you haven't included the `jekyll-paginate` gem. Ensure you have `gems: [jekyll-paginate]` in your configuration file.
        Source: /home/ubuntu/mydomain.com
   Destination: /home/ubuntu/mydomain.com/_site
   Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
   Generating...
                done in 1.177 seconds.
   Deprecation: You appear to have pagination turned on, but you haven't     included the `jekyll-paginate` gem. Ensure you have `gems: [jekyll-paginate]` in your configuration file.
   Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/home/ubuntu/mydomain.com'
   Configuration file: /home/ubuntu/mydomain.com/_config.yml
   jekyll 3.1.2 | Error:  Cannot assign requested address - bind(2) for 'host:port'
```

So how do I fix this problem.

I want to pull my github pages to the cloud server at regular time, and I found someone did it like

```
crontab -e 

*/2 * * * * cd ~/mydomain.com/; git pull >> /tmp/github_blog_pull_record.log 2>&1;
```

And I don't know what does `*/2 * * * * cd ~/mydomain.com/; git pull >> /tmp/github_blog_pull_record.log 2>&1;` mean?

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1** : You've already have a process working with 80 port, try changing your `jekyll serve` port `sudo jekyll serve --port 81 --host 'my server ip address'`. Note: Why running jekyll with sudo ? No secure at all !

**Question 2** : `*/2 * * * * cd ~/mydomain.com/; ...` is a [cron task](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) that will pull you github repository every days at 02:00.

Note: it's better to ask one question at a time.

Comment: I restart my server that run the jekyll serve, it shows `Could not find 'jekyll' (>= 0), ... from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:22:in <main>'`,  but I really install jekyll